# stacknotify google chrome extension

Tags: app, chrome-extensions, google-chrome

[image: screenshot]

### About

Your Stack Overflow notification inbox, right into your browser's toolbar.

- it checks for new notifications every minute
- shows a notification badge for new items
- supports all Stack Exchange websites

---

This is a pretty basic extension. 
Hopefully, it will get more features soon.

I hope you'll enjoy it ;)

#### License

free

#### Download

From [Google Extensions Library](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacknotify/jekfdfagmfmibhidlkkecfchoghlldak)

### Contact

http://nuc.gr

### Code

js, html, css

Comment: @nuc: This look promising, but before I install this, can you choose which stack exchange site you want to follow ? I would like to follow the Android , not just the Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @edelcom You get the same notifications as your StackExchange inbox, which means they include all Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: I don't know if this qualifies as an answer on this site, but I have a go at it, all the same. **This extension does what it says it does.** So this is a nice addition to the chrome toolbar. *Thanks* - hope to see some more work from you.

Comment: @nuc this is great!!! One thing that I guess you can't fix is that sometimes (not initially though) it will mark the items as read, so there will be a new item, and the extensions tells me this, but on the websites it doesn't tell me there are new items,

Comment: @Jonathan Actually, there is a way to fix this. I hope I'll get some time during this week and provide an update. Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: @Nuc,, great :)

Comment: @Edelcom: but how does one tell if it is working? Mine isn't showing anything yet...

Comment: Weird. I go into the Developer Tools to try and figure out why the thing isn't working, and then it ends up working after all...

Comment: @Nuc something else I noticed is that if I leave chrome open on my desktop then the notifications go there and not to my laptop. It would be great if you could make them go to both.

Comment: This is a great app @nuc! Thanks a lot for sharing.

Comment: @nuc Is a great idea, but the counter is not refreshed until browser is restarted. This is very annoying. Please update. Thank you!

Comment: Ping. Ping. As many have noted here and in reviews in the Chrome store, this sucker is currently broken. It's a great extension and we'd love to have it back! Is this going to be addressed?

Comment: I installed this tonight, because the OS X menubar app Stack Exchange Notifier stopped working today. It shows all my recent notifications up to the time I installed it, but no new notifications since then.

Answer (score 6):

This is really cool! Thank you! But it needs an update asap!

There is an issue with the counter.. Please resolve!

Answer (score 4):

You know, you should probably set the "Developer website" to point here rather than to http://nuc.gr.

I was just trying to get back here from chrome://extensions, and upon opening your page, I almost despaired of getting back here — it just looked so sparse. Fortunately, I persevered until I found that the word "geek" linked to [your apple.stackexchange.com profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1475/nuc), from which it was easy to get back here (just had to click accounts, then stackapps, then open the only "question" listed, as it happened).

Or, if you'd rather, I guess you could just put a clearly-marked link to this page onto http://nuc.gr; that would only be a tiny bit less convenient for those headed back here, and would still let people know about [your cute kid](http://www.flickr.com/photos/nuc/4685521273/) ;-).

Answer (score 3):

Could you add the ability to specify whether questions open in incognito or not? Or even if you're currently browsing in incognito and you click on a question; it'll open in incognito. Would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

May have missed this in the extension, but it would be great to add the ability to get notifications for new questions in specific tag(s).